# Where is the Mac OSX Mail blacklist / whitelist location(s)

Tags: email, macos

For the record, I have asked a related question on the *Ask Different* exchange, but I don't think it's really the type of question they are used to over there.

I am used to BASH line commands, and I've made (unrelated) modifications via terminal before. This is why I'm here.

---

I do not use the VIP list in my Mac Mail (Version 12.2).

And yet somehow, I accidentally added my wife to the VIP list.

It was very easy to use the GUI to remove her name from the VIP list, and in fact the extraneous "VIP" list is no longer even present in my list of mailboxes. Great.

But now we get to the problem.

When she was removed from the VIP list, she was somehow added to the Junk list. Every email that I receive from her – from either of her three email accounts – is unceremoniously dumped into Junk Mail. This did not happen before the VIP incident, and I can't seem to "re-approve" her contact as a valid and good email now.

**I believe that I can BASH in and modify a whitelist/blacklist from the command line. My issue is that I do not know where Apple locates these on the Mac system. Can anyone please point me to the germane file?**

Here are some details:

- The VIP addition/subtraction was the very clear and distinct moment
  that this happened
- My wife is in my Apple contacts
- POP3
- Mac 10.14.6

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I can provide any more specific information.